# How do I download an Amazon RDS database from an instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds, snapshot

A while ago, I shut down an RDS instance and took a snapshot. Now, a year later, I'd like to download that database. So I restored the snapshot by creating a new instance which is up and running. But I cannot figure out how to download the db.

I have tried connecting to the database via phpMyAdmin but it keeps refusing to connect (even though I have added the IP for phpmyadmin to the security group on amazon). Is there a way to download the database via command line? Something else has to be easier...

Comment: Use the `mysqldump` command to dump the database to a text file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [download RDS snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916899/download-rds-snapshot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no other way but connecting to your instance and using any tool you might want to use to do the job - backup

This question was answered before.

[download RDS snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916899/download-rds-snapshot)