# Where can I find AWS RDS snapshot hostname?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a MySQL instance running on RDS and I have created a snapshot and I read I can [connect to snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14916918/355507). But I can't find snapshot specific hostname there on RDS management console. Can I really connect to AWS RDS snapshot using mysql client like I connect to instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an implication in the linked answer that you would need to restore the snapshot to an RDS instance. A snapshot isn't a live MySQL database -- you can't connect to it and use that state until you [restore a new RDS instance from that snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html). Here's how snapshots are defined in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.BackingUpAndRestoringAmazonRDSInstances.html), if it helps:

> DB snapshots are user-initiated and enable you to back up your DB
>   instance in a known state as frequently as you wish, and then restore
>   to that specific state at any time. DB snapshots can be created with
>   the Amazon RDS console or the CreateDBSnapshot action in the Amazon
>   RDS API. DB snapshots are kept until you explicitly delete them with
>   the Amazon RDS console or the DeleteDBSnapshot action in the Amazon
>   RDS API.

You can restore from a snapshot from the AWS console, or programmatically through the:

- [CLI: restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot.html)
- [API: RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot.html)